# how to make tcl commands in hierarchy

Tags: tcl

i want to generates the following tcl commands, the arguments are passing in a tree structure

```
proc find { args } {
    array set opt {-do ""  -delete ""}
    foreach {key value} $args {
        if {![info exists opt($key)]} {
            error "Wrong type '$key' The argument must have "
        }
        set opt($key) $value
    }
    if {$opt({-do) == ""} {
        .... 
        if {$opt(-value ) == ""} {
            ..........
            if {$opt(-set ) == ""} {
                .......... 
            }
        }
    }
    if {$opt({-delete) == ""} {
    } 
} 
proc -do "I1"   

proc -do "I1" -value "t"    #print this results only

proc -do "I1" -value "t" -set "A"   #should not touch function { proc -do "I1" -value "" }(print this results only)

proc -delete  "all"

proc -delete  "all"  -select "I4"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just merge in the user's arguments and then validate afterwards:

```
proc find { args } {
    array set opt $args                  ;# user

    # now figure out how to dispatch:
    if {$opt(-do) ne "" &&
        [info exists opt(-value)] && $opt(-value) ne "" &&
        [info exists opt(-set)]   && $opt(-set) ne ""
    } {
        set_value $opt(-do) $opt(-value) $opt(-set)
    } elseif {$opt(-delete) ne ""} {
        delete $opt(-delete)
    } else {
        display_hierarchy
    }
}

proc set_value {key value set} {
    # ...
}

proc delete {key} {
    # ...
}

prod display_hierarchy {} {
    # ...
}
```

Note, `puts` takes a single string to print (http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/puts.htm), so
the following is a syntax error

```
    puts -value "t" -set "A"
```